# Sqlcommand are old fashion new one is Dataset

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

I wrote this type of command for my application.BUT my lecturer told me those things are Old fashion,USE new things like DATASET.. I wanted to know you guys is that correct ? Those kind of thigs are outdated ? Date Set is new way to do this ?

```
protected void btn_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONN_STR))
    {
      con.Open(); 

      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_BinCardManager SET ItemName = @ItemName WHERE ItemNo = @ItemNo"), con)
      {

        // TODO: fill in param values with real values
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", "my item name");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNo", 1);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `USE new things like DATASET`. OMG. Has your teacher been in comma for the last 5 years?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov he is just a lecturer ,not a industry person.. thats why i actually asked it from industry persons

Comment: How does one get inside of a comma?

Comment: He always use TableAdapter and something

Comment: @JoshEinstein, by using DataSets :-)

Answer (score 2):

The classes you are using are the nuts and bolts of pretty much all data access technologies in .NET. There are abstractions around it such as DataSets, LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, etc. But in the end they all use SqlConnection and friends.

In fact, of the 3 technologies I mentioned, DataSets are the ones that have been largely discarded and have little or no support outside of the .NET 2.0-era tooling.

Comment: you mean Dataset is outdated ?

Comment: I can't think of any compelling reason to use a DataSet anymore. The only benefit it still has over LINQ to SQL is that you can use it to cache local data without an actual database behind it very easily. But for actual data access, yes, it was surpassed years ago.

Comment: Yes, it has been surpassed by EF. But L2S is still very capable and even supports a few things EF does not yet support, whereas DataSet and table adapters have pretty much been swept into the dustbin of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

DataSet used DataReader internally to populate date. Also dataset works in disconnected mode, but your code is not outdated by any means.

Your teacher is may be talking about using [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Comment: You use datasets if you want to work with a set of tables and rows while disconnected from the data source. Using a dataset is not always an optimal solution for designing data access. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

NO, your code is not at all Old fashioned..its perfectly simple for your requirement.

use `DATASET` when its really needed.. like, when you want to take some data offline, and modify it and again reflect back the changes to database..

In fact `SqlCommand` command is not an alternative for `DATASET`..

`DATASET` is something which can hold tables retrieved from database or locally created..

`SqlCommand` is something which helps you get/insert/update data from/to database table

even if you are using `DATASET` you still need `SqlCommand`.. then **there is no question of `Sqlcommand` being oldfashioned and `Dataset` being the new one**

Comment: And if you claim `SqlCommand` to be old-fashioned - then data sets are, too! They both are "outdated" in that today, I would argue, one should start with an **ORM** (rather than "bare-bones" rows&columns data access) - unless specific reasons make this not an option.